# Как мне вывести переменную с JavaScript в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть выпадающий список из чисел от 1 до 10. При умножении на один из 3х вариантов должно получиться произведение чисел.Как мне вывести результат умножения (LICENSEPLAN#*Number of licenses) на экране вместо суммы 340$ который уже там находится.

Comment: _"У меня есть выпадающий список из чисел..."_ А у нас такого списка нет. Поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
const priceElement = document.getElementById('price')        
const a = 30
const b = 4
priceElement.innerHTML = a * b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <h1>Тест. <span id="test"></span></h1>
    <script>
        test.innerText = "123"
    </script>
```